NDSolve suddenly extremely slow after including an interpolating function
I am trying to solve the following coupled differential equations:
Hamiltonian = 
 h {{0, \[CapitalOmega]1/2, 0}, {\[CapitalOmega]1/
     2, \[CapitalDelta], \[CapitalOmega]3/2}, {0, \[CapitalOmega]3/
     2, \[Delta] + -s3[eext[t]] + s1[eext[t]]}} /. 
  parameters; vec =  {c1[t], c2[t], c3[t]}; sol = 
 NDSolve[Join[
   Thread[D[vec, t] == (-I/h) Hamiltonian . vec], {c1[0] == 1, 
    c2[0] == 0, c3[0] == 0}], vec, {t, 0, time}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]

Without the "-s3[eext[t]] + s1[eext[t]" functions in the last part of the Hamiltonian the code runs just fine within a reasonable time but whenever I add those extra functions it slows down considerably even thought the functions are not very complicated. They are just linear functions that barely change in the scales of the problem. I should also mention that s1 and s3 are interpolating functions that are defined for certain points in specific intervals.
s1[elec_] := (B /. YbF)*
   Evaluate[
    RotorStarkLevel[0, 0][elec/(B/Subscript[\[Mu], e]) /. YbF] - 
     RotorStarkLevel[0, 0][0]];
s3[elec_] := (B /. YbF)*
   Evaluate[
    RotorStarkLevel[1, 0][elec/(B/Subscript[\[Mu], e]) /. YbF] - 
     RotorStarkLevel[1, 0][0]];

The RotorStarkLevel here is a package that leads to an interpolating function.
any help appreciated!

Fit the slowly varying interpolating function by a polynomial of order 2 or 3.
